# Object.observe instead of dirty checking with AngularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, object.observe, ecmascript-2016

Is there a way to use `Object.observe` instead of the dirty checking in AngularJS 1.x, if supported by the browser? This could significantly increase the performance.

`Object.observe` is currently supported at least by Google Chrome: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es7/

Comment: Use for what? Dirty checking what?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way of doing this. It's in the long term plan for Angular: http://ng-learn.org/2014/03/AngularJS-2-Status-Preview/#change_detection

Comment: That it is planned for AngularJS 2.0 I already know. But would not it be relatively easy to integrate `Object.observe` already in AngularJS 1.x?

Comment: I think it's safe to say that if it were *easy* to implement, they would have already done so.